# Android App - Keyboard Type

Tags: android, types, keyboard

We have a user name and telephone field. User opens android keyboard and enters user name. Then in the keyboard user clicks the ‘Next’ button and it launches the telephone type keyboard.
But the same behavior is not observed in case of swift keyboard. If user chooses swift keyboard, App doesn’t bring the telephone keyboard on click of telephone field.

What is going wrong here? Any suggestion.
Is there anyway I can enforce user to use Android Keyboard?

Comment: Which localization are you using? I know SwiftKey has a numerical keypad; I use it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot force the users to use a particular keyboard (ime).  The user is able to select whatever ime they prefer.  In your app, all you can do is provide a hint as to which type of characters the user is going to be entering (text, numbers, etc). It is up to the particular ime to decide how to allow the user to input the text.